# Loading external class c++

Tags: c++, c, dll, vtable, loadlibrary

I am trying to load a class defined in a .dll file. However there are two slightly different ways of defining the class in the dll. I'm not sure which is the more legit way to do it, and I don't know why the second way also works. Here is a simple example:

**Method 1:**
In `main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <memory>
#include "bar.h"

using namespace std;

typedef bar* (* MYDLLPROC)();

int main()
{
    unique_ptr<bar> theresult;
    auto thelib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("foo.dll"));

    if (thelib != NULL) {
        MYDLLPROC theprocs = (MYDLLPROC)GetProcAddress(thelib, "Myfoo");
        cout << "load successfully" << endl;
        theresult.reset(theprocs());
        theresult->printmsg();
    } else {
        cout << "cannot load the dll" << endl;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

The `bar` is defined as a pure virtual class in `bar.h`:

```
class bar {
public:
    virtual ~bar() {};
    virtual void printmsg() = 0;
};
```

In the `foo.dll` source file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include "bar.h"

using namespace std;

class foo: public bar {
public:
    foo() { cout << "foo is instantiated" << endl; }
    ~foo() {}
    void printmsg() final { cout << "msg from foo print" << endl; }
};

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) foo* __cdecl Myfoo()
{
    return new foo();
}
```

In the first method the pure virtual class `bar` is used as an interface, and it makes sense that its member function(s) is overridden by that in `foo` when the dll is loaded.

However, I found that `foo` doesn't have to be derived from `bar`, everything still works as long as `foo` has a Vtable:

In the second method, everything is the same except for the definition of `foo`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

class foo {
public:
    foo() { cout << "foo is instantiated" << endl; }
    virtual ~foo() {}
    virtual void printmsg() final { cout << "msg from foo print" << endl; }
};

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) foo* __cdecl Myfoo()
{
    return new foo();
}
```

Could anyone please let me know why the second method works? I'm a bit confused because `foo` and `bar` are not related but the member function in `bar` can still be overridden.

Comment: The second is undefined behavior caused cast in your test program. Unfortunately some times undefined behavior appears to work.

Comment: @drescherjm  Oh sorry, that is a typo, I have corrected to Myfoo. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @drescherjm Does this mean although the second method works however it could go wrong sometimes?

Comment: ***Does this mean although the second method works however it could go wrong sometimes?*** Yes, I believe so. In the 2nd dll the `foo` class is not a `bar` but by casting `typedef bar* (* MYDLLPROC)();` you are lying to the compiler telling it to "trust me the returned pointer  is a pointer to a bar"

Comment: @drescherjm Makes sense! Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you cast a function returning `foo*` as a function returning `bar*` and then invoking it.

The end result is that you have a pointer to `foo` which is a pointer to an unrelated type `bar`. Using it in any way will lead to [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

It appears to work in this specific case because the position of the `printmsg` virtual function in both vtables is the same, so invoking `bar::printmsg` on an instance of `foo` simply calls the "Nth entry in the vtable". If you add another virtual member to `foo` before `printmsg`, then it might get called instead (or the program might crash).

Comment: Ah indeed! I added another function and the order of the two functions are different in ```foo``` and  ```bar```. Then the new added function is called instead.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

First example is very fragile because it implicitly relies on `foo` and `bar` being pointer-interchangeble.

Second example is broken because function `Myfoo` returns a pointer to class `foo` that is not related to `bar` and dereferencing it causes undefined behavior.

Function signature must match the function implemented in the dll. What you have right now is basically a wild `reinterpret_cast` from `foo *` to `bar *`.

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand that the second method is ill defined. Indeed the first method causes object slicing, however I have to define the actual class in the dll. To the main function the actual class is unknown, so I need to make an interface for it by using a pure virtual class. So I guess it will be safe as long as in the main function I only call the member functions declared in the pure virtual class?

Comment: @Weigh No object slicing happens in the first example. And if you are going to return a pointer to abstract class you need to make sure that function implemented in dll returns a pointer to this class and NOT a pointer to derived class. Loading function as returning `bar *` while in dll it is declared as returning `foo *` is not a good idea.

Comment: so should I up cast ```foo``` to ```bar``` in the function ```Myfoo()```?